# How to get matching data from other table?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Using Postgres, I have 2 tables:

- The first called territories with columns sid, agent and postcode.
- The second called postcodes, with columns id, postcode and geometry.

How can I put the geometry column data from the table postcodes into the table territories with the matching postcode?

Comment: Did you try with join of both tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a query:

```
select t.*, p.geometry
  from territories as t left join postcodes p on t.postcode=p.postcode
```

Thats works only if there are not duplicateds postcodes in postcodes table.

If you want to update the table territories, first add the column and then update it:

```
update territories t set geometry = p.geometry
  from postcodes p
  where t.postcode=p.postcode
```